# What is set of basic solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation

What is the set of basic solutions regarding homogeneous systems? Is the set of basic solutions the same as basis? There is many questions about finding a Set of Basic Solutions to a Homogeneous System but I can't really find any definition.

Comment: Different books may mean different things. Can you give some context?

Comment: Vector group $\ X= X_1, X_2, .... , X_t$ is called a basis set of solutions of $\ AX=0$ if it fulfills following requirements:  

1) every vector of X is the solution for $\ AX=0$  

2) $\ X$ is linearly independent set  

3) ??? I don't know how to translate it

Comment: We call this the null space, or kernel, of $A$. It is a vector space (prove this).

Comment: What do you mean by "Is the set of basic solutions the same as basis?' If you ask if the null space can be created by different basis vectors? then it depends on the null space

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* set of basic solutions. *A* set of basic solutions will form a basis for the vector space of all solutions.